# Making the element of a list a class attribute of an instance variable

Tags: python, list, for-loop

I'm trying to build an UNO game and I'm in the process of creating the deck. Right now I'm stuck with creating the action cards to then append to the entire deck. This is my code:

```
class Card:
  def __init__(self, symbol, colour, is_action_card = False, is_wild_card = False):
    self.symbol = symbol
    self.colour = colour
    self.is_action_card = is_action_card
    self.is_wild_card = is_wild_card

  def __repr__(self):
    return "{symbol}, {colour}".format(symbol=self.symbol, colour=self.colour)


colour_list = ["red", "green", "blue", "yellow"]
reverse_card = Card("reverse", "", True)
reverse_cards = []

for colour in colour_list:
  reverse_card.colour = colour
  reverse_cards.append([reverse_card])

print(reverse_cards)
# prints [[reverse, yellow], [reverse, yellow], [reverse, yellow], [reverse, yellow]]
```

I'm trying to create a loop which will assign each colour inside `colour_list` to the instance `reverse_card` as its “colour” attribute, but when I run it I get the result above. What I'm trying to get is `[[reverse, red], [reverse, green], [reverse, blue], [reverse, yellow]]`, what am I missing in my loop?

Answer (score 0):

You are appending the same `Card` instance 4 times to the list and keep changing its `colour` attribute. The last one that persists is "yellow".

You are missing to create a separate `Card` instance for each colour:

```
for colour in colour_list:
  reverse_card = Card("reverse", colour, True)
  reverse_cards.append([reverse_card])
```